# Find the initial percentage of a range slider that uses quadratic function

Tags: reactjs, math, slider

I am attempting to create a slider that utilizes both linear and quadratic functions to update the value of the slider. In this case I'm particularly concerned of the quadratic.

In my specific case, the range is [5, 4000]

[image: Slider]

And this works as I want, 500 is ~50%, 5 is the minimum and 4000 is the maximum.

However, I am having troubles getting the initial state to act properly.

Eg:
[image: Not Working Slider]

In which this case, the initial value should be 100, which percentage wise equates to ~22%, but in initial state its about ~2% because it's not using the quadratic version on mount. I'm specifically having trouble creating a general equation to translate the quadratic to a percentage--if that makes sense.

Relevant code:

```js
const [percent, setPercent] = useState(
  getPercentage(immediateValue.current, min, max)
);

const getPercentage = (current: number, min: number, max: number) =>
  ((current - min) * 100) / (max - min);

const getValue = (
  percent: number,
  min: number,
  max: number,
  type: ValueT,
  touched: boolean
) => {
  const value = Math.round((percent * (max - min)) / 100 + min);

  if (type === "quadratic" && touched) {
    const nv = value / max;
    return Math.round((max - 1) * Math.pow(nv, 2.5) + min);
  }

  return value;
};

  useEffect(() => {
    let value = getSteppedValue(getValue(percent, min, max, valueType, true), step);

    if (percent === 0) {
      value = min;
    }
    if (value > max) {
      value = max;
    }
    if (value < min) {
      value = min;
    }

    updateValue(value);
    onChange && onChange(value);
  }, [percent]);
```

Comment: There is a unique linear function that goes through points `(0, 5)` and `(100, 4000)`. However, there are infinitely many quadratics through the same two points. You'll have to decide which one you want to use, before worrying about the code to do it.

Comment: Could you perhaps point me to a resource of what you mean?
Or do you just mean slope intercept form? Sorry I'm getting mixed up with how you mean theres a unique linear function (makes sense), but infinite quadratics.

Comment: You want to map each percentage `x` in `[0, 100]` to a value `y` in `[5, 4000]`. With a linear mapping `y = a x + b` there is only one way to do it. However, with a quadratic `y = a x^2 + b x + c` there are many possible ways to do it, in fact infinitely many. See e.g. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+5+%2B+3995+*+x%5E2+%2F+10000%2C+y+%3D+5+%2B+2000+*+x+%2F+100+%2B+1995+*+x%5E2+%2F+10000+for+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+100) two different such quadratics. You need to add some additional constraint stronger than just "*quadratic function*" for a unique solution.